# Wrong execution on function in JS

Tags: javascript, validation

I have this code, but somewhy when i use this function to validate my input field everything works, except + and - keys, even thought i noted them as true. What have i done wrong?

```
function validateNumber(event)
{
    var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;

    if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 37 ||
        event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 107 || event.keyCode == 109 ||
        event.keyCode == 32 )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(key < 48 || key > 57)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
};
```

Comment: Exact duplicate: [HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

Comment: i took code from that question, but did some changes, and now it doesnt works as intend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see you checking for `189` (<kbd>-</kbd>) and `187` (<kbd>=</kbd>, which is really what happens when you type <kbd>+</kbd>). You might want to check if the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed for <kbd>+</kbd>.

As already noted, it's overall a wrong way to validate user input. You need to inspect the value of the input, not individual keystrokes.

First, define a validation function that would check an arbitrary text with a regexp:

```
function checkArithmetic(str) {
    var regexp = /^[0-9+-]$/;
    return regexp.test(str);
}
```

Next, add a handler to your input element:

```
input.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    var value = input.value;

    if (checkArithmetic(value)) {
        // OK!
    } else {
        // error
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: the problem is that i dont have access to form by itself, i can only use some js, to do any  actions based on id